# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application stuck on Upgrading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i have recently upgraded my SP 2013 RTM version to SP1 and my SQL Server to Service Pack2 of SQL 2012.

[image: FoundationWS]
Now, am seeing that Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application is stuck on starting. i tried the below steps:

1. restarted the SP admin service
2. Restarted the SP timer service
3. performed the IISRESET
4. Rebooted the server [ i am having 2 server farm - 1 wfe and another server with sql server installed]

but even after doing all these steps , am still seeing this service stuck on  `"Upgrading"` .

What must be done in order to change it to `Started`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this was posted about a month ago or so, but in case you still haven't figured out, all you need to do is to execute the following command from SharePoint Management Shell:

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action start -servicetype spwebservice
```

This starts the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application Service back up, which should resolve the issue.

If your site doesn't come back up right away, do an iis reset as well but running this command:

```
iisreset
```

I hope this helps.

Pete

Comment: Thanks. This command helped me when this service was in Starting/Provisioning state.